# How can we change the opacity of image on 2Drender?

Tags: xtk

I would to know if there is a function that change the opasity of image on 2D render (like the action of hover on the canvas)
thanks a lot,AMAL

Answer (score 0):

2D render is basic a HTML canvas, opacity can be done by settings globalAlpha property :

```
ctx.globalAlpha=0.2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following line of code in renderer2D:

```
var _labelOpacity = 1;//_volume._labelmap._opacity;
```

(https://github.com/xtk/X/blob/master/visualization/renderer2D.js#L1277)

I don't know the reason the opacity was changed to be always 1, but I uncommented the right side and it worked for me.